# JMeter view results tree requests showing error

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Why is this second request happening (**Request2-1**) here and how to solve it.

[image: Jmeter]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is redirected and there is not permission to access the resource.

> The HTTP [403 Forbidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) client error status response code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.

Please check the request details in the view result tree by clicking `Request->Request` Body and `Request->Request` Headers
[image]
You need to ensure that the request is permitted.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the resources, you're trying to access require [authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication) and you're not supplying valid authentication context.

If you do [HTTP Status Code 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) means that the user is not allowed to access the endpoint.

See How to use [JMeter for Login Authentication](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421705-How-to-use-JMeter-for-Login-Authentication) article for more information on example bypassing login challenge in JMeter tests.

Answer (score 0):

If "Follow Redirects" is selected in HTTP Request, it will follow the redirects and groups each redirect under the original request as in the image you posted.

[image]

Some APIs can redirect, this is normal. Response failure is caused by the request content sent. Check the parameters and body values you sent.